# Type '(event: React.MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(e?: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> | undefined) => void'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have:

```
<StyledPill
        size="small"
        label="See All Destinations"
        onClick={handleClick}
        data-index={0}
        featured={selectedSearchType === 0}
        leftIcon={<AllDestinationsIcon />}
      />
```

Where `StyledPill` has types:

```
export interface IPillProps {
  size: 'small' | 'medium';
  className?: string;
  featured?: boolean;
  label: string | ReactElement;
  disabled?: boolean;
  counter?: boolean;
  onClick?: (e?: MouseEvent) => void;
  leftIcon?: ReactElement<IconProps>;
  onClickLeftIcon?: (e?: MouseEvent) => void;
  rightIcon?: ReactElement<IconProps>;
  onClickRightIcon?: (e?: MouseEvent) => void;
  image?: ReactElement;
}
```

and `handleClick` is:

```
  const handleClick = useCallback((event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    console.log('shamoon1', {event}, {selectedSearchType});
    preventClickPropagation(event, false, (e) => setSelectedSearchType(Number((e.target as HTMLElement).dataset.index)))
  },
    []
  );
```

But this gives me a type error on the `onClick`:

```
Type '(event: React.MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(e?: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> | undefined) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'e' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>'.
```

Comment: It sounds like your parameter for `handleClick` should be typed as `event: React.MouseEvent | undefined`.

Comment: why u use useCallback here, you know ====== useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders

Comment: What do you propose instead?

Comment: simple arrow function or function expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error it seems like your anonymous function should have a different signature:

Your anonymous fn signature (in `useCallback`)
`(event: React.MouseEvent) => void`

What TypeScript is expecting:
`(e?: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> | undefined) => void`

I imagine if you update the typing to `MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> | undefined` for `event` then that'll mean you have to change the implementation to match.